# TeX4ht / tex4ebook: labeling unnumbered equations

Tags: equations, labels, tex4ht, htlatex, tex4ebook

I am trying to understand whether it is possible to allow labels in `equation*`-environments as long as they are not referred. This is allowed in `pdflatex`, but when compiling with `tex4ebook` (with default parameters), it will produce an error. Here is a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{equation*}\label{py}
  a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

And the error message of `tex4ebook`:

```
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./test.tex   2    Extra \endcsname.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./test.4ct   2    Missing \endcsname inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./test.4ct   2    Missing \endcsname inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    8    Missing \endcsname inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    8    Missing \endcsname inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    8    Missing \endcsname inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    8    Missing \endcsname inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: ?    8    Missing \endcsname inserted.
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
```

**Remark**: if one deletes the line `\section{Introduction}`, then the error vanishes.

Comment: Please be more specific what you are doing, and what the error is. Running `htlatex` as well as `latex` + `tex4ht` on your MWE doesn't give an error, but produces the expected result. (TeXlive 2021, Linux)

Comment: @gernot Thanks. I have added a bit more details about the context.

Comment: ah, this happens only with `tex4ebook`, not with `make4ht`, so it must be something wrong in tex4ebook itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, what purpose has `\label` on unnumbered equation? It cannot be used to reference to that equation. When you put any object that can be referenced to, like `\section` in your case, the `\label` will point to that object, no to the equation. So it cannot work as intended.

However, even if it doesn't serve an useful function, it is indeed unfortunate that it produces an error. `tex4ebook` needs to track all HTML files and their order. All sections or chapters produce separate files, and `tex4ebook` reads special TOC file to find their order. The file has `.4tc` extension and it can look like this:

```
\doTocEntry\tocsection{1}{\csname a:TocLink\endcsname{2}{x2-10001}{QQ2-2-1}{Introduction}}{1}\relax
```

The `a:TocLink` macro has lot of parameters, but  important for our use case is `x2-10001`. It contains the section ID. We then need to resolve the HTML filename for this section. TeX4ht keeps track of all ID's and files in the `.xref` file:

```
...
\:CrossWord{)F2F-}{samplese1.html}{1}%
...
\:CrossWord{)Qx2-10001}{2}{1}%
\:CrossWord{)Qx2-10001}{2}{1}%
```

TeX4ht puts some prefix for each referencable item, so files are surrounded by `)F<file number>F-`, and `\label` IDS have `)Q<ID>`. As you can see, there is duplicate entry for the section ID. It is produced by `\label` inside `equation*`. If you put `\label` directly after `\section`, this problem wouldn't happen. Why is it a problem? You can read value of `\:CrossWord` using `\Ref` command. `\Ref{)Qx2-10001}` should produce `2`, which is the number of HTML file that contains this section. But if there are duplicate IDS, it will produce their list separated by commas, so it produces `2, 2` in our case.

`tex4ebook` uses nested `\Ref` commands to find the section HTML filename:

```
 \Ref{)F\Ref{)Q#1}F-}
```

Normally, it would produce `samplese1.html`, but because of duplicate ID, it doesn't return the filename and it produces an error message instead.

To fix that, we can get only the first item returned by `\Ref{)Qx2-10001}` and use that to find the filename. It needs quite bit change in the `tex4ebook` sources, but you can emulate it using the following configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% get filename for the section label
% sometimes, TeX4ht returns list of file numbers for label. we must use just
% the first number. we use the LaTeX 3 sequence functions to achieve that
\tl_new:N\ncx:hfilename
\def\ncx:newhfile#1{
  % cw:)Q#1 is csname of tag from the xref file
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nc\l_tmpa_seq{cw:)Q#1}
  \seq_get_left:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  %\tl_to_str:N \l_tmpa_tl
  % \RefFileNumber returns file name for the given file number
  \tl_set:Nx \ncx:hfilename {\RefFileNumber{\l_tmpa_tl}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\catcode`\:=11
\def\ncxtable{%
\EndP
\HtmlParOff
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\special{t4ht>\jobname.ncx}
% We don't want crosslinks in xml
% Basic sctructure of the ncx file
\NoFonts
{\HCode{<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\Hnewline}}
{\a:NcxDoctype}
{\Tg<ncx xmlns="http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/ncx/" version="2005-1">}{}
% To print document map, we customize the tableofcontents. We don't want TOC title,
% so:
\let\contentsname=\empty
\Configure{tableofcontents}{\boolfalse{tocnoempty}\Tg<navMap>}{%
    \usetoclevels{part,appendix,chapter,likechapter,appendixsec,section,likesection,subsection,appendixsubsec,likesubsection,subsubsection,likesubsubsection,appendixsubsubsec,subsubsubsection,paragraph}%
    \ifbool{tocnoempty}{}%
    {\HCode{<navPoint id="mainentry" playOrder="1">
      <navLabel><text>Document</text></navLabel>
      <content src="\jobname.\:html" />
      </navPoint>}}%
    \Tg</navMap>}{}{}{}  
 % We need to configure TocLink
 % in navmapsrc is link to the file and anchor, where chapter or section is located
 \def\navmapsrc{}  
 \Configure{TocLink}{%
   \ncx:newhfile{##2}
   \def\navmapsrc{\ncx:hfilename\:sharp ##2}
   \opf:registerfilename{\ncx:hfilename}
   ##4
 }
 % Configuraion of entries
 \expandafter\resettoclevels\expandafter{\a:resettoclevels}%
 \confnavsections%
 \HtmlParOff%
 \Configure{toTocLink}{}{}%
 \Configure{NavSection}{\booltrue{tocnoempty}\HCode{\Hnewline<navPoint id="navPoint-}%
  \stepnavpoint\HCode{" playOrder="}%
  \the\navpoint\HCode{">\Hnewline<navLabel>\Hnewline<text><navmark type="\curr:sect:type">}%
}{\HCode{</text>\Hnewline%
  </navLabel>\Hnewline}%
 \HCode{<content src="\navmapsrc" />}%
}{\HCode{</navmark>}}{\HCode{</navPoint>\Hnewline}}
% Meta inf
\ncx:head
% Book title
\ncx:title
\tableofcontents[part,appendix,chapter,likechapter,appendixsec,section,likesection,appendixsubsec,subsection,likesubsection]%
%Hack to get close tag working
\HCode{</ncx>}
\EndNoFonts
\special{t4ht<\jobname.ncx}
 \HtmlParOn
}
\catcode`\:=12
\EndPreamble
```

The important code is this:

```
\tl_new:N\ncx:hfilename
\def\ncx:newhfile#1{
  % cw:)Q#1 is csname of tag from the xref file
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nc\l_tmpa_seq{cw:)Q#1}
  \seq_get_left:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  %\tl_to_str:N \l_tmpa_tl
  % \RefFileNumber returns file name for the given file number
  \tl_set:Nx \ncx:hfilename {\RefFileNumber{\l_tmpa_tl}}
}
```

It uses the LaTeX 3 sequence list to parse the comma separated list and to return the first item. `\seq_set_from_clist:Nc\l_tmpa_seq{cw:)Q#1}` uses the control sequence used internally to keep the reference. `\RefFileNumber` can be used instad of `\Ref{)F<number>F-}`. The `\ncx:hfilename` token list is then defined. It can be used in register the filename in `\ncxtable`:

```
 \Configure{TocLink}{%
   \ncx:newhfile{##2}
   \def\navmapsrc{\ncx:hfilename\:sharp ##2}
   \opf:registerfilename{\ncx:hfilename}
   ##4
 }
```

This inserts correct link to the Epub TOC, and also registers the HTML file.

Compile using

```
 tex4ebook -c config.cfg filename.tex
```

Comment: This kind of labels usually appear in the case that the equation was at first labeled and referred to, then modified since it is no longer referred to, I guess.

Comment: @Yai0Phah ah, it makes sense then. I've updated `tex4ebook` sources, so this should be fixed in the next release.